# WordPress markup erroneously showing up in page

Tags: wordpress

We are exporting code from our Production server[WP-v3.9.24] and importing that code to a Pre-production server[WP-v5.2.4]. Our code on Prod displays features just fine like the "+" icon and "Continue Reading".

When we move that same code to Pre-prod, those features like "+ Continue reading" and others instead show what appears to be WP markup language. I hope this is enough information. Is anyone familiar with this? Can someone help steer me in the right direction? I will post a sample URL showing things working properly, and a URL showing how things are not displaying properly:

```
https://www.distancecme.com/course/bls-nccp-anytime/?portfolioID=1314 - this display properly.
https://dcmeqa.wpengine.com/course/live-bls-nccp-anytime/ - this does not display properly.
```

I don't think I'm able to show screenshots, so please simply use those above links to see how the code is displayed properly, and not properly.

Some of the code which does not resolve, in its raw form is here[it's a public site so here's the WP markup code]:

```
NCCR BLS

Designed to meet the NREMTs latest requirement for BLS Providers, the National Continued Competency Requirements or NCCR. This program meets the required hours for this program. These are LIVE courses and are 10 classes of the 24 hour refresher for a total of 20 hours. You do not have to take them in order. For a complete description please view our free DEMO. CECBEMS/CAPCE Accredited F-5 VILT

[accordian class="" id=""]
[toggle title="Continue Reading" open="no"]
Airway/Respiration/Ventilation: 1.5 Hours

Ventilation [1 Hours]

Oxygenation [0.5 Hour]
Cardiovascular: 6 Hours

Post-Resuscitation Care [0.5 Hour]

Ventricular Assist Devices [0.5 Hour]

Stroke [1 Hour]

Cardiac Arrest [2 Hours]

Pediatric Cardiac Arrest [2 Hours]
Trauma: 1.5 Hours

Trauma Triage [0.5 Hour]

Central Nervous System (CNS) Injury [0.5 Hour]

Hemorrhage Control [0.5 Hour]
Medical: 6 Hours

Special Healthcare Needs [1.5 Hours]

OB Emergencies [0.5 Hour]

Infectious Diseases [0.5 Hour]

Pain Management [0.5 Hour]

Psychiatric and Behavioral Emergencies[0.5 Hour]

Toxicological Emergencies – Opioids[0.5 Hour]

Neurological Emergencies – Seizures[0.5 Hour]

Endocrine Emergencies – Diabetes[1 Hour]

Immunological Emergencies [0.5 Hour]
Operations: 5 Hours

At-Risk Populations [0.5 Hour]

Ambulance Safety [0.5 Hour]

Field Triage—Disasters/MCIs [0.5 Hour]

EMS Provider Hygiene, Safety, and Vaccinations [0.5 Hour]

EMS Culture of Safety[0.5 Hour]

Pediatric Transport [0.5 Hour]

Crew Resource Management [1 Hour]

EMS Research[0.5 Hour]

Evidence Based Guidelines [0.5 Hour]

CAPCE/CECBEMS Accredited 17-GANN-F5-0011

[/toggle]
[/accordian]

[/one_half]

[one_half last="yes" class="" id=""]

Anytime EMS CEU Package

This EMS bundle provides anytime access to over 100 self-directed learning modules. Each module is 1.0 hour in length and upon successful completion offers 1.0 credit via CAPCE F-3 for a total distributive learning credit of 100 plus CEUs. This bundle provides quality education in a recorded format, Perfect for the busy EMT, AEMT, Paramedic. These courses are accepted by the National Registry of EMTs for recertification of EMTs, AEMTs, and Paramedics for the Distributive learning portion of your recertification. Save by bundling this with our live paramedic or EMT refresher course for a total refresher package. (Once issued we can not refund the cost of the Anytime Program).

This can be bundled with the live paramedic or live EMT refresher course for a complete recertification package.
[accordian class="" id=""]
[toggle title="Continue Reading" open="no"]
Do you prefer to call in with your credit card number? We can take your order by phone. Call 267-417-0009, M-F 9-5 eastern.

Length:

1 hour each course over 100 courses for a total of 100 Hours

Continuing Education Hours Provided:

1 credits each course – CECBEMS/CAPCE F-3 APPROVED

[/toggle]
[/accordian]

[/one_half]


[button link="https://store.distancecme.com/dcmecartadd/dcme/addproducttocart/sku/243US18022/" color="default" size="" type="" shape="" target="_self" title="" gradient_colors="|" gradient_hover_colors="|" accent_color="" accent_hover_color="" bevel_color="" border_width="1px" shadow="" icon="" icon_divider="yes" icon_position="left" modal="" animation_type="0" animation_direction="down" animation_speed="0.1" class="" id=""]Enroll Now[/button]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the content isn't getting passed through the [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter. What you're seeing are called [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), and they are turned into HTML by the `the_content` filter which is normally called by the `the_content()` function.

If you can, I would recommend you just use

```
the_content();
```

to output the content. Sometimes you may want to get the content as a string for additional processing before outputting it, in which case just make sure you pass the content through the `the_content` filter like so

```
$content = get_the_content();
apply_filters( 'the_content', $content ); /* converts shortcodes into HTML */
echo $content;
```

Comment: hi, Nathaniel thx for your post. i am scanning online articles and do not yet see how to use the_content function. have you used it, can you provide a code example/reference? as in using the code i posted above? basically literally these codes appear in the display, when they're supposed to be starting an accordion: [accordian class="" id=""] [toggle title="Continue Reading" open="no"]. instead of those, you should see a "+" and "Continue Reading", not unresolved code. still looking online, and may start stabbing at code seeing if something sticks. thx again for your answer, i suppose helped!

Comment: Actually, looking further I see that you are using the Avada theme. Avada properly uses the_content or at least I know they do in newer versions of the theme. It's used in `Avada/includes/lib/inc/functions.php`. A couple things come to mind. First, there was a conversion process that happened when Avada changed their shortcodes. More info at https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/how-to/how-to-convert-your-website-to-avada-50/. But more importantly, you said this was happening withthe `/courses` pages. That sounds like a custom post type that is getting generated by a plugin.

Comment: Do you know which plugin might be handling the courses pages? Also, you'll probably want to buy the newest update to your Avada theme if it hasn't been updated in a while.